# How to use MVC4 Dynamic Html inputs

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC and using MVC4. I have a series of cascading drop downs that I'm populating with AJAX calls. Customer > Family > Assembly - The assembly determines how many Baluns (objects with attributes) I need the user to fill in, the number of Baluns objects is based on what the requirement is for that assembly.

I created a separate object for each item and a viewmodel for this view. I'm then passing the listOfBaluns to a partial view to loop through and create the HTML for however many are needed.

When I submit the form I am always only seeing the 1st Balun object's attributes. From my understanding I'm using the partial view correctly to loop through the list of Balun Objects, but those don't appear on the Post for either FormCollection or in Request.Form.

In the code I included I'm just testing to see if I can get 2 baluns working, that should explain why I'm explicitly adding 2 balunrecords to the list in the view model.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the View -

```
@model Nortech_Intranet.ViewModels.BalunTuningEntryViewModel
@using Nortech_Intranet.Models.BalunModels

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="whiteBodyContainer">
        @*Text Entry fields*@
        <table style="margin: auto;">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.balunTuningRecord.Start_Timestamp)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.balunTuningRecord.Start_Timestamp, new { @Value = @System.DateTime.Now } )
                </td>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.balunTuningRecord.Work_Order)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.balunTuningRecord.Work_Order)
                </td>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.balunTuningRecord.Serial_Number)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.balunTuningRecord.Serial_Number)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr />    

        <table style="margin: auto;">
            <tr>
                @Html.Partial("_RenderBalun", Model.balunList)
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create Tuning Record" />
    </p>
}
```

ViewModel -

```
using Nortech_Intranet.Models.BalunModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Nortech_Intranet.ViewModels
{
    public class BalunTuningEntryViewModel
    {
        public List<Customer> customerList { get; set; }
        public List<Family> familyList { get; set; }
        public List<Assembly> assemblyList { get; set; }
        public List<NWAnalyzerModel> nwAnalyzerModelList { get; set; }
        public List<NWAnalyzerCAL_ID> nwAnalyzerCAL_IDList { get; set; }
        public List<TestUser> testUserList { get; set; }
        public List<BalunRecord> balunList { get; set; }

        public BalunTuningRecord balunTuningRecord { get; set; }

        public BalunTuningEntryViewModel() : base ()
        {
            balunList = new List<BalunRecord>();

            BalunRecord newRecord = new BalunRecord();
            balunList.Add(newRecord);
            BalunRecord newRecord2 = new BalunRecord();
            balunList.Add(newRecord2);
        }

        public BalunTuningEntryViewModel(int i)
        {
            balunList = new List<BalunRecord>();

            for (int counter = 0; counter < i; counter++)
            {
                BalunRecord newRecord = new BalunRecord();
                balunList.Add(newRecord);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Partial View -

```
@model IEnumerable<Nortech_Intranet.Models.BalunModels.BalunRecord>
@using Nortech_Intranet.Models.BalunModels

@{
    int counter = 1;
    foreach(BalunRecord record in Model)
    {
    <td>
        <table id="@("tblBalun"+@counter)"  style="border: 2px solid gray; visibility: collapse;">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><label>Balun #@counter</label></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => record.Tuning_Cap_1)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => record.Tuning_Cap_1, new { id = "ddlBalun" + @counter + "Cap" + "1" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => record.Tuning_Cap_2)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => record.Tuning_Cap_2, new { id = "ddlBalun" + @counter + "Cap" + "2" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>       

        counter = counter + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simplify the code and show only the minimum required to understand the problem? I think the problem is not difficult to solve, but noone is going to review so many code. At least me. Buy the way: too much test, too much code, but your problem is not clear at all. Tons of code and... where is the controller's action?

Comment: I tried to be as detailed as possible but good suggestion, I shortened up the code so now it's got all the fat cut out of it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the solution was to loop through and use the indexing for the model. Here is the new section in the view that solved the problem -

```
@{
    var counter = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.balunList.Count; i++)
    {
    <td>
    <table id="@("tblBalun" + @counter)"  style="border: 2px solid gray; visibility: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><label>Balun #@counter</label></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.balunList[i].Tuning_Cap_1)
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.balunList[i].Tuning_Cap_1, new { id = "ddlBalun" + @counter + "Cap" + "1" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.balunList[i].Tuning_Cap_2)
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.balunList[i].Tuning_Cap_2, new { id = "ddlBalun" + @counter + "Cap" + "2" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
        counter++;
    }   
}
```